# Wordpress custom taxonomy meta box goes hidden for un expected hide-if-js class

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have a problem about WordPress custom taxonomy meta box.

I register a custom taxonomy under a custom post type, other taxonomy are displayed except one for the `hide-if-js` class. Automatically it add with the meta box.

[image: Problem]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating taxonomy. With plugin or without. If you are creating this without plugin then simply remove this class from the html file.

Comment: I just add this code to create taxonomy ...
register_taxonomy( ... , .... , array(
                'hierarchical'      => true,
                'labels'            => array(
                    'menu_name'         => __( 'Product Size' ),
                ),
                'show_ui'           => true,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'query_var'         => true,
                'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'product-size' ),
            ) );